# Check if browser is supported by salesforce right on visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, community, support, browser

In short, we need to display to the community users kinda warning in case if their browsers are not among supported by salesforce.
The option we've come up with so far, is just to check user's agent from javascript function located and called on the main template page.

But using described solution, we've basically just hard-coded list of supported browsers inside js function. Yes, we could move it to custom settings, but it wouldn't solve the problem. Each new sf release we would need to review the list of supported browsers and change our js code or custom settings appropriately.

The question is: maybe there is some function in the standard sf-included js-scripts, which are included into every vf page ?
Or are there some other flexible approaches to identify if browser is supported by sf ?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see the custom setting should do in your case. These kind of scenarios are Ideal use of Custom settings.

Comment: That's not the case. As I described in my question, I don't wanna change values in custom settings after each new sf release (when they drop some old browser support). Ideally there should be an approach which would handle this automatically, kinda some js function from sf library or similar.